# What is the difference between the sendmail submit queue and standard queue?

Tags: linux, email, smtp, sendmail

I'm confused on the purpose of the sendmail submit queue (by default /var/spool/clientmqueue).  I think it's used to store messages when sendmail is ran in mail-submission program mode instead of daemon mode... but that's still confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the bat book:

> In a non-set-user-id root world, sendmail runs under two guises. In
>   one guise, it is run by root to function as a listening daemon. This
>   listening daemon is just like the listening daemon of earlier
>   versions, except that, instead of running as root no matter who ran
>   it, it now runs as root only if root runs it.
>
> In its second guise, sendmail runs as an ordinary user to collect
>   locally submitted messages. In this mode of operation, sendmail is
>   set-group-id to a special group, so it runs in that group no matter
>   who runs it. That group owns and has write permission to a separate
>   queue into which locally submitted deferred messages are placed.

Comment: I own editions 2,3 and 4 of the book and have never regretted one cent of it!

Answer (score 2):

sendmail, when using submit.cf, uses `/var/spool/clientmqueue`, the client-only mail queue, which holds messages that were not delivered to the sendmail daemon. Messages in the client-only queue are delivered by the client “daemon,” which is really acting as a client queue runner vs standard queue.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't quite understand... it sounds like that would be a holding area for outbound messages but I definitely see outbound messages in the standard queue area (/var/spool/mqueue)

Answer (score 1):

clientmqueue is for messages submitted by non-root users running sendmail locally on the host to deliver mail, and mqueue is for messages being processed by the running sendmail daemon (usually delivered by SMTP).

Comment: Oooh! I like that explanation. Concise and clear.